# How to show active jobs using AS400 (JT400) client access software?

Tags: java, ibm-midrange, jt400

I want to develop as400 client access software. I want to monitor disk space, cpu usage etc.. And Job list. I got job list. But I want get to active jobs only. Please help me.

This is my job List Code :

```
try {
    AS400 system = new AS400 ("SERVER","USER", "PASS");
    JobList jobList = new JobList(system);
    Enumeration list = jobList.getJobs();
    while (list.hasMoreElements())  {
         Job  j= (Job) list.nextElement();
         String GCPU = Integer.toString(j.getCPUUsed());
         System.out.println("Name " + j.getName() + " | Job NO : " + j.getNumber() + " | User : " + j.getUser() + " | CPU USED : " + j.getCPUUsed());
      // System.out.println("Date Entered : " + j.getDate() + " | Status : " + j.getStatus() + " | Type : " + j.getType());

    }
} catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: What is your question / error?

Comment: this code give all jobs. but i want active jobs only. plz help me. tnx frnd

Comment: can u help me to get only active job list. plz Thanks.

Comment: Please, use a more descriptive title for your exact programmatic/technical problem. E.g. "How to show active jobs using as400(jt400) client access software?"

Comment: Thank you friend, my English is so bad. thnks again. did you know how to do that ?

Comment: Can Anyone help me to do this. plz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 JobList jobList = new JobList(system);
 jobList.addJobSelectionCriteria(JobList.SELECTION_PRIMARY_JOB_STATUS_ACTIVE, Boolean.TRUE);
 jobList.addJobSelectionCriteria(JobList.SELECTION_PRIMARY_JOB_STATUS_JOBQ, Boolean.FALSE);
 jobList.addJobSelectionCriteria(JobList.SELECTION_PRIMARY_JOB_STATUS_OUTQ, Boolean.FALSE);
 Enumeration jobs = jobList.getJobs();
```

The list of job selection criteria is maintained internally even when this JobList is closed and re-used. To start over with a new set of job selection criteria, call clearJobSelectionCriteria().

See the [Javadoc](http://javadoc.midrange.com/jtopen/com/ibm/as400/access/JobList.html) for more details.